# XML file reader using C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<a><b>26a83f12c782</b><c>128</c><d>12</d></a>



 static void ReadXml1()
   {
       string b = null;
       double c = 0;
       double d = 0;

        using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader("Testxml.xml"))
       {
           if (xmlReader != null)
           {
               while (xmlReader.Read())
               {
                   if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                   {
                       switch (xmlReader.Name)
                       {
                           case "b":
                               b = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();

                               break;
                           case "c":
                               c = double.Parse(xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                               break;
                           case "d":
                               d = double.Parse(xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                               break;
                       }
                   }
               }
       }
           }

   }
```

The first line is in the Testxml.xml file. Case "c" is never hit. But if I add a space after `</b>` in xml file, it will work. But I can't change the xml file. So how do I get the value of c element.

Comment: Is your case "b" hit?  It looks like you are looping over the first layer of XML, not the second where `<c>` exists

Comment: Got it. Need to add goto case "c" and goto case "d" after case "c" and case "d" respectively instead of break.

Comment: You need the break; otherwise, the code will fall through to the next case.  I'm thinking that the xmlReader.Read() is only seeing the `<a>` level of XML, not the children, which contain `<c>`

Answer (score 3):

ReadElementContentAsString performs a read to move to the next node after consuming the content. In your code, you do an additional read, skipping over the next element declaration. In the case you provided, you can get away with out the while loop altogether, e.g.:

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader("<a><b>26a83f12c782</b><c>128</c><d>12</d></a>");
string b = null;
double c = 0;
double d = 0;
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr, new XmlReaderSettings() { IgnoreWhitespace = true }))
{
    xmlReader.MoveToContent();
    xmlReader.ReadStartElement("a", "");
    b = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString("b", "");
    c = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble("c", "");
    d = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble("d", "");
}
```

- List item